# Search array of nested objects by given field

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have the following structure of the Room object.

```
type Room struct {
Id          bson.ObjectId       `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
Title       string              `json:"title" bson:"title"`
Description string              `json:"description" bson:"description,omitempty"`
Type        string              `json:"type" bson:"type,omitempty"`
AdminId     bson.ObjectId       `json:"admin_id" bson:"admin_id"`
CreatedOn   time.Time           `json:"created_on" bson:"created_on"`
Messages    []Message           `json:"messages" bson:"messages,omitempty"`}
```

Where Messages is nested array of objects that has the following structure

```
type Message struct {
Id      bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
Text        string          `json:"text" bson:"text"`
Author      Author          `json:"author" bson:"author"`
CreatedOn   time.Time   `json:"createdon" bson:"created_on"`
Reply       []Message   `json:"reply" bson:"reply,omitempty"`}
```

I want to perform the search query by the messages in the collection of rooms. I tried using `"$in"` but I did not help me.

Moreover, I have to search elements by matching values. I can do this using bson regular expressions.

```
&bson.RegEx{Pattern: textToFind, Options: "i"}
```

Summing up I need to search messages by the `Text` field in the nested object in the Room document.

P.S. Sorry for possible mistakes, English is not my native language.

**UPDATE**

Basically, I want to find all the messages in the given room that contains some substring. For example, search for all messages in the room (chat) 'A' that contains 'some text' substring.

Comment: You can try something like `collection.Find(bson.M{"messages.text": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: textToFind, Options: "i"}})`

Comment: @Veeram I've tried but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below mongo shell aggregation pipeline.

`$match`es on some room attribute (ex `_id`).

`$unwind` messages( transform `messages` array into object ) in the room.

`$match`es on input regex against `text` field to filter `messages`.

`$group`s the message objects back into `messages` array.

`$project` to exclude `_id` and include only `messages` for output.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$match:{"_id":roomid}}, 
{$unwind:"$messages"}, 
{$match:{"messages.text": { $regex: /textToFind/i } }},
{$group:{_id:null,messages:{$push:"$messages"}}}, 
{$project:{_id:0, messages:1}})
```

Below is untested mgo equivalent.

```
match1 := bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{
        "_id": roomid,
    },
}

unwind := bson.M{
    "$unwind": "$messages",
}

match2 := bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{"messages.text": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: textToFind, Options: "i"}},
}

group := bson.M{
    "$group": bson.M{
        "_id": null,
        "messages": bson.M{
            "$push": "$messages",
        },
    },
}

project := bson.M{
    "$project":  bson.M{
        "_id": 0, 
        "messages":1,
    },
}

all := []bson.M{match1, unwind, match2, group, project}
pipe := collection.Pipe(all)

result := []bson.M{}
err := pipe.All(&result)
```